# Using async-await to execute a task AFTER dropping a collection from mongodb database

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, async-await

I am trying to use async await to execute an http request before executing some other code.
More precisely, I would like to drop a collection in my mongodb database, before executing some others tasks.  Here's what I did:

> app.component.ts:

```
  async deleteRiskRatingData2() {
      await this.saveInformationService
      .deleteRiskRatingInformation()
      .subscribe((data: string) => {
        console.log('Deleting risk Rating');
        console.log(this.riskRatingTable);
      });
      console.log('TASKS TO BE EXECUTED AFTER DROPIING COLLECTION');
  }
```

> save-information.service.ts

```
  deleteRiskRatingInformation() {
    console.log('INIDE deleteRiskRatingInformation INSIDE SAVE-INFORMATION.SERVICE');
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/dropRiskRatingCollection`);
  }
```

In the backend:

> server.js

```
router.route('/dropRiskRatingCollection').get((req, res) => {
    RiskRating.remove({},(err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json("Risk Rating Collection has been dropped!");
    });
});
```

And this is what happens:
[image]

I though my implementation of Async/Await should allow me to execute the:

```
  console.log('TASKS TO BE EXECUTED AFTER DROPPING COLLECTION');
```

After the dropping of the collection request has been executed. But that didn't happen as you see. And I really don't understand why.
Any idea why is this happening? Is my logic flawed somewhere? And how can I achieve my goal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async`-`await` work only with Promises. You're try them with `Observable`s. That won't work. `Observable`s have an API that let's you convert them into `Promise`s though. You can call a `toPromise` method on them in order to do that.

Try this:

```
async deleteRiskRatingData2() {
  const data = await this.saveInformationService.deleteRiskRatingInformation().toPromise();
  console.log('Deleting risk Rating');
  console.log(this.riskRatingTable);
  console.log('TASKS TO BE EXECUTED AFTER DROPIING COLLECTION');
}
```

**NOTE:** It's fine if you're trying this just for the sake of testing it. But I think you should not really switch back to promises just to use `async`-`await`, to make your code look synchronous.

Comment: Why 'But I think you should not really switch back to promises just to use async-await, to make your code look synchronous.'?

Comment: Well, there are some tasks that are better left to run asynchronously. Also by converting your Observables into Promises, you lose all the powerful operators that you could eventually apply to Observables.

Comment: Okay but what if I want to display the response object data. Is it doable with toPromise?

Comment: Yes. We've already assigned the response to the `const` named `data`, that we declared in the method.